# Why accessing a numpy array is 6 times slower than Pillow image with Cython

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, cython

I have an RGB image where every pixel has to be recalculated with a special formula and for performance reasons I'm using Cython for the hot loops.

My code is working with a Pillow Image object passed to Cython code where each pixel is accessed as `image[x, y] = something`, which uses Python `__getitem__` and thus very slow (I measure and it take 50% of function time on get/set item).

My idea was to use a numpy array and possibly a Cython [memory view](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) to speed this up, but the new duration of the changed function is now 6 times slower!!!

(BTW the original `calculate_color` function I use is waaaaay more complex than the example below, so don't ask me to rewrite the piece using FOO or BAR. I'm trying to compare `r_001` and `r_002`)

Code `main.py`

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pyximport
pyximport.install(setup_args={"include_dirs":np.get_include()})
import rendering

size = 2000, 2000
mode = 'RGB'
mult = np.ones(size[0] * size[1], np.long)

im_new = Image.new(mode, size)
rendering.r_001(im_new.load(), mult, size[0], size[1])

im_new = Image.new(mode, size)
rendering.r_002(np.array(im_new), mult, size[0], size[1])
```

Code `rendering.pyx`

```
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()
import numpy as np

def r_001(object image, np.ndarray[long, ndim=1] multiplier, long w, long h):
    cdef long x, y, x_index, y_index

    for y from 0 <= y < h-1:
        y_index = w * y
        for x from 0 <= x < w-1:
            x_index = x + y_index
            m = multiplier[x_index]
            r, g, b = image[x, y]
            image[x, y] = calculate_color(m, r, g, b)


def r_002(np.ndarray[char, ndim=3] image, np.ndarray[long, ndim=1] multiplier, long w, long h):
    cdef long x, y, x_index, y_index

    for y from 0 <= y < h-1:
        y_index = w * y
        for x from 0 <= x < w-1:
            x_index = x + y_index
            m = multiplier[x_index]
            r, g, b = image[x, y]
            r, g, b = calculate_color(m, r, g, b)
            image[x, y] = <char>r, <char>g, <char>b


cdef inline tuple calculate_color(long m, long r, long g, long b):
    cdef long a = 75
    r = (a * m + r * m) // 256
    g = (a * m + g * m) // 256
    b = (a * m + b * m) // 256
    if r > 255: r = 255
    if g > 255: g = 255
    if b > 255: b = 255
    return r, g, b
```

**Using cProfile, I get that `r_001` takes 1.53s to run while `r_002` takes 9.68s.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a good idea of what's going wrong by using `cython -a` on the code and looking at the annotated html. Essentially the problem lines are:

```
r, g, b = image[x, y]
# ...
image[x, y] = <char>r, <char>g, <char>b
```

Cython is usually only quick when indexing individual elements - for partial indexing it falls back on `__getitem__` and then (in this case) tuple unpacking and packing. One way of rewriting the code would be:

```
r = image[x, y, 0]
g = image[x, y, 1]
b = image[x, y, 2]
# and equivalently for the assignment
```

You could look at speeding up `calculate_color` by having it [return a "`ctuple`"](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#types):

```
cdef (char, char, char) calculate_color(... # as before ):
```

You should also set the type of `r`, `g` and `b` (in `r_002`) to `char`.

---

If it were me I'd probably make `image` a 2D array of 32 bit ints, and get the separate colours with bit masking. It would be a more significant change to your code, but would make the indexing easier.

---

`cProfile` is a bad way of timing individual functions - depending on the contents it can add a lot of overhead when they make calls. This tends not to be the case for Cython since it can't "see inside" Cython functions. It's good for getting an overview of a whole program and where it's using time, but for measuring performance of a self-contained small chunk use `timeit` or similar instead.

Comment: Thank you. I had looked inside the C code for the original function but not the 2nd function since the Cython docs ([specially this one](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) appeared to say I could efficiently access the array that way. I am happy with the results, but do you know why do I need to split the access in 3 get/set lines?

Comment: BTW, I have a humongous code base and cProfile it is necessary to narrow down some hot loops. Of course I measure individual code with timeit

Comment: @JBernardo You're using `np.ndarray` rather than memoryviews (which is the section of documentation you linked to). Memoryviews are a newer addition and do some things a bit better. You can certainly get a 1D memoryview efficiently by slicing a 2/3D memoryview. I don't think that applies for `ndarray`. The three lines are needed to avoid it using Python tuple unpacking, which is slow(ish). I can't think of a good way to avoid it.

Comment: I did use a memory view on a 3rd attempt but it was actually even slower and I didn't include the code. I might try again later on, but I got good improvement using both ctuple and accessing each component individually. Thank you